# WFS in ArcGIS 10.4: how to configure?

Tags: arcmap, wfs

I want to use this WFS 
url: http://ccff02.minfin.fgov.be/geoservices/arcgis/services/WMS/Cadastral_Layers/MapServer/WFSServer?

I can use it without any problems in QGIS. I do not succeed to use it in ArcMap 10.4.

Coordinate system of my dataframe in ArcMap: Belge_Lambert_1972
WKID: 31370 Authority: EPSG

I want to use this feature type: Cadastral_parcel. I know that this WFS prefers the use of WKID: 3812 or WKID: 4326

Is it possible to limit the download to a bbox in WKID: 31370?

Answer (score 1):

The WFS doesn't as you say 'prefer' the two coordinate reference systems cited, it only supports them.

```
<wfs:FeatureType>
    <wfs:Name>CL:Cadastral_parcel</wfs:Name>
    <wfs:Title>Cadastral_parcel</wfs:Title>
    <wfs:DefaultSRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:3812</wfs:DefaultSRS>
    <wfs:OtherSRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4326</wfs:OtherSRS>
    <wfs:OutputFormats>
        <wfs:Format>text/xml; subType=gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlsf/1.0.0/0</wfs:Format>
    </wfs:OutputFormats>
    <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
        <ows:LowerCorner>2.5299071005992668 49.484616315528285</ows:LowerCorner>
        <ows:UpperCorner>6.4590126554566467 51.50583616059005</ows:UpperCorner>
    </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</wfs:FeatureType>
```

By default it will use `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:3812` but otherwise you can request `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4326`.

In QGIS 3 you have automatic reprojection, so if you have a project using the EPSG:31370 projection, then QGIS will translate the request into one of those supported by the WFS.  If you want to use EPSG:31370 in ArcMap you'll have to configure something similar.

Comment: At the office we are not yet working with QGIS 3. 
Can you have one more look at this wfs? 
I can only download 1000 parcels . For my project I need 4000 parcels at the same time. Is this possible? 
Is it only possible from WFS version 2?  
I have the same limitation of 1000 parcels with org2ogr.

Comment: QGIS 2, also allows reprojection on the fly, but does not have it on by default.   The WFS service has `<ows:Constraint name="DefaultMaxFeatures"><ows:Value>1000</ows:Value></ows:Constraint>` So if you want more than that I think you just need to use the `maxFeatures=4000&` parameter